# System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I got an error like this:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase`8[TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRole'. System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)  ArgumentException: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]' violates the constraint of type 'TRole'.
> System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
> TypeLoadException: GenericArguments[1], 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase`8[TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TRole'.
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.Instantiate(Type[] inst)
> System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)

StartUp.cs

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<HiGeekNewsDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Program.cs

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                SeedData.Initialize(services);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        };

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace? I believe the interesting part is further down in the call to `MakeGenericType`

Comment: So `UserStoreBase` has a generic constraint `TRole` that you are trying to violate. Probably caused by https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.cs#L50. But you should probably post more context.